# How to add object in laravel relationships

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

How to add extra object in laravel relationship when fatch data.

Here is my code:

```php
$list = new self;
$list = $list->where('uuid', $uuid);
$list = $list->where('user_id', $user->id)->orWhere('to_user_id', $user->id);
$list = $list->with(['touser' => function($q1) {
    $q1 = $q1->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'user_image', 'is_active', 'is_profile_completed', 'is_verified');
}]);
$list->with(['user' => function($q1) {
    $q1 = $q1->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'user_image', 'is_active', 'is_profile_completed', 'is_verified');
}]);

$list = $list->first();
```

I want to add extra object in response like:

```json
"Contest": {
   "name": NULL,
   "type": 0
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you trying to an extra property to your object which you are getting from your query? or you want to add an extra object to the result collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to add extra objects in response

The first option is

You have to define the eloquent relationship in the list model like this

```
public function contest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contest::class);
}
```

and then you can eager load that relationship using a method like this

```
$list->with('contest')->first();
```

another option is
You can set custom relationships like this

```
$list->setRelation('contest', collect(['name'=>null,'type':0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$list->prepend([
            'Contest' => [
                 'name' => null,
                 'type' => 0
            ]
        ]);
```